# Casting from base class to unknown derived class

Tags: c++, templates, casting

Given an object initialized like so:

```
Base* a = new Derived();
Container<Base> c(a);
```

where

```
class Base {
  ...
  protected:
    ~Base();
}

class Derived : public Base {...};

template <typename T>
class Container {
  private:
    T* object;

  public:
    Container(T* o) : object(o) {}
    void deleteObject() {
      delete object;  // Object must be casted to (unknown) derived type to call destructor.
    }
};
```

Obviously this is very simplified from the actual code, but the question is how do I cast `object` from its templated type to its actual, derived type (if they are different), which is not known?

I cannot modify `Base` or `Derived`, or even any of the code calling `Container`, only the `Container` class itself.

Comment: If you cannot modify `Base` atleast, you're kinda screwed.

Comment: @AdamZalcman Updated to clarify that a bit.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall: you can't cast to an unknown type. Casting means "retrieving a known interface from an object of unknown type (possibly with run-time checking)". Casting to unknown type doesn't make sense. Perhaps you problem is different, and so you should provide more detail.

Comment: After the latest edit, I officially label this as impossible, as long as you only get a `Base*` pointer passed. If you'd atleast get a `Derived*` pointer passed, it would still be possible.

Comment: **Fix** Base. A polymorphic base class without a virtual destructor is a bug.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes As stated, I can't modify `Base`. It's part of code given by the professor, and is the sort of thing explicitly & purposefully done to make things more challenging.

Comment: Make `Container` take second template parameter `Derived` (since you can modify `Container`): `Container<Base,Derived>` and use **static_cast** to cast the pointer.

Comment: Did you post the exact code? `Container<Base> = new C<T>(a);` doesn't look like a valid statement to me.

Comment: @AzzA: He's not allowed to change the calling code (the one at the top).

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes You're right, that got confused in the translation. Fixed.

Comment: @Xeo Then he can give `deleteObject` a template parameter: `template< typename D> void deleteObject() { delete static_cast<D*>(object); }`. Or it's forbidden too and you really need to hack object memory layout?

Comment: @Azza: That doesn't seem to be forbidden, but is potentially *very* dangerous.

Comment: @Xeo Why? If classes are not related (if that's what you are concern about), it won't compile - it's **static_cast**. Or there is some different danger?

Comment: @AzzA: The user might well not specify the correct derived class, or even a superbase class of `Base`.

Comment: @Xeo Well, I think if user chooses to use such design in the first place, he should bloody be prepared to supply the correct `Derived` class to `deleteObject` in case there are 2 derived classes. Otherwise, he might as well just stomp on the keyboard and hope it'll produce compilable code.

Comment: The destructor '~Base()' is 'protected'? how can you 'delete object'? Did the code compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're able to change the creation code, you might get away with this:

```
template<class T>
void deleter(void* p){
  delete static_cast<T*>(p);
}

template<class T>
class Container{
private:
  T* obj;
  typedef void (*deleter_func)(void*);
  deleter_func obj_deleter;

public:
  Container(T* o, deleter_func df)
    : obj(o), obj_deleter(df) {}
  void deleteObject(){ obj_deleter(obj); }
};
```

And in the calling code:

```
Base* a = new Derived();
Container<Base> c(a, &deleter<Derived>);
```

Comment: I can't change `Base` or `Derived`. I'll update my question stating so.

Comment: My problem ended up morphing a bit from what I asked here, and was thus solved in a different way; sorry for all the confusion around it. I like this answer the best of what's here though given the problem I *did* ask.

Comment: You said you can only change `Container`, and can't change the code calling `Container`. I take it you've relaxed this second bit? i.e. you allow that the call to construct Container now takes two parameters, the object and its deleter.

Answer (score 4):

You need to template the constructor and store a type-erased deleter. This is how `shared_ptr` does it.

```
template <typename T>
class Container {
  private:
    T* object;
    std::function<void(T*)> deleter;
  public:
    template<typename U> Container(U* o) : object(o) {
        deleter = [](T* ptr) { delete static_cast<U*>(ptr); };
    }
    void deleteObject() {
        deleter(object);
    }
};
```

Comment: Won't work if he only gets a `Base*` passed in, which is what I was hinting at in my comment.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `deleter = []() { delete static_cast<U*>(o); };` ?

Comment: This uses lambdas, a C++11 feature. Is it possible to answer this without lambdas?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: No, that would involve unnecessary overhead. I made a mistake in the calling code. You could use a static member function for a similar effect.#

Comment: @Xeo: If the Container only ever sees `Base*`, then there's nothing it can do to magically determine the correct type.

Comment: @Xeo, another edit required instead I think. The lambda won't have access to `o`. (But I'm no expert on C++ lambdas) `deleter = [](T* ptr) { delete static_cast<U*>(ptr); };`

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** (since this is homework): Look up the keyword `virtual`.

Comment: I know about `virtual`, but I cannot change `Base` or `Derived`, so that doesn't help.

Comment: Then I wish you the very best of luck! ☻

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot change both the **Base** or **Derived** or make the destructor virtual, you can make the deleteObject a template function

```
template <typename T>
class Container {
  private:
    T* object;

  public:
    Container(T* o) : object(o) {}


    template <typename U>
    void deleteObject() {
      U* c = static_cast<U*>(object);
      delete c;
    }
};


int main(void)
{
    Base* a = new Derived();
    Container<Base> *b = new Container<Base>(a);


    b->deleteObject<Derived>();
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: -1. This assumes that we know the correct type at deletion. The whole point of this question is that we have a pointer b where it isn't obvious what it's real type is.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid  The virtual destructor solution is the most logical solution. This is just one of the other solutions correct within the constraints of the question

Comment: This answer breaks the rules. It says "I cannot modify Base or Derived, or even any of the code calling Container, only the Container class itself."  You have changed `main`, whereas we are only allowed to change the code in `Container`.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I didn't realize you cannot modify `Container` signature as well...

If you can modify your `deleteObject`:

```
template <typename T>
class Container {
  private:
    T* object;

  public:
    Container(T* o) : object(o) {}
    template< typename PDerived >
    void deleteObject() {
      delete static_cast< PDerived* >( object ); 
    }
};

Base* a = new Derived();
Container<Base> c(a);

c.deleteObject<Derived>();
```

EDIT: Someone posted same solution earlier.

Comment: -1: We don't know what c contains a Derived. The whole point of this exercise is that the developer can't simply call `c.deleteObject<Derived>();`

Comment: @AaronMcDaid Well, he said he can modify `Container`, just not the calling code he showed. Anyway, I don't really care that you `-1` it, but it just too bad you don't see that every single answer in this topic supplies `Derived` as a explicit template parameter one way or another. Without `Base` being virtual or without specifying `Derived` somehow as template parameter explicitly, you won't get it working unless you use knowledge about object memory layout which is not guaranteed to be portable across compilers.

Comment: Nobody's perfect. As far as I was aware, it is normal on StackOverflow to tell people that you have downvoted and to give a reason to do so. Perhaps the question is pretty much unsolvable. It might be better to highlight that the question, as asked, is not possible (in any reasonably sane/portable) way. One either needs to use `virtual` or else one needs to make changes to the way Container is called. i.e. This requirement (from the question) must be relaxed: `I cannot modify Base or Derived, or even any of the code calling Container,`   And I've just tried to undo my downvote.